# Div Class Labeled Invalid

Tags: html

I'v been having some trouble with my second div class, welcome, showing up as overlapping or unclosed, when it is not doing either. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
<body>
<header>
<div class="nav"> 
<!--This is the main navigation bar code-->
<ul>
  <li class="Home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="DesignBrief"><a class="#" href="#">Design Brief</a></li>
  <li class="Information"><a href="#">Information</a></li>
  <li class="About"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="News"><a href="#">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
<div class="welcome">
<div style="height: 500px">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: umm..... add a `</div>` to close it??? Really, it can't be more trivial than this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is way too trivial to be worth an answer

Comment: Because that division is unclosed.

Comment: voting to close a question because you might think it's trivial isnt valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing `</div>` tag.

Your final code should look like this:

```
<body>
<header>
<div class="nav"> 
<!--This is the main navigation bar code-->
<ul>
  <li class="Home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="DesignBrief"><a class="#" href="#">Design Brief</a></li>
  <li class="Information"><a href="#">Information</a></li>
  <li class="About"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="News"><a href="#">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</header>
<div class="welcome">
<div style="height: 500px">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```